# What is difference between these tags <% <%: <%= in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

The title contain my whole question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<% /* Is a codeblock */ for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) { } %>
<%= "Writes something to the output stream" /* Response.Write */ %>
<%: "HTML-encodes this <b>hello</b> to the output stream" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a good explanation about the <%, <%= and <%# syntax and their usage, please read [this article](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx).

The <%: syntax is new in .Net 4 and is used for encoding HTML output. See [this article of ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

`<% %>` **is used just to execute server side code** 
 
ex.  `<%   if(oject){...} %>`

`<%= %>` **is used execute server side code and return value** 
 
ex. `<%=Html.Encode(Item["Name"]) %>`

`<%: %>` **is used execute server side code but it will return** Html
   Encoded string 
 
ex.  `<%Item["Name"] %>`

Source : [What is difference between these tags <%, <%: , and <%= in ASP.NET MVC 2?](http://thingswelearned.com/article/Details/76dc823b-bdfe-4d4c-98a5-91d720593ce8)